# React Redux store update rerenders whole app

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

On `onClick` `SigninButton` calls `ONTOGGLE_MODAL_SIGNIN` which updates `ui.isSigninModalActive` from store. Everything works fine but I see that my whole app gets re-rendered when `ui.isSigninModalActive` toggles on and off. Is this normal behaviour? I had thought that you have to `store.subscribe` and update that component's inner state and that component alone gets updated (and not the whole app) when store updates. If the whole app re-renders, then what is the point of `store.subscribe`? Or did I mess up somewhere? Thanks for the help in advance.

signin_button.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { store } from '../../../store/store';
import { onToggleModal } from '../../../actions/ui';

export const SigninButton = () => (
  <svg viewBox="0 0 32 32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" className="signin-button"
           onClick={ () => store.dispatch(onToggleModal('signin')) }>
    <path d="M0 0h24.997C25.55 0 26 .444 26 1c0 .552-.45 1-1.003 1H0V0"/>
  </svg>
);
```

router.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Router, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store, history } from '../../store/store';
import App from '../../ui/containers/app_container';
import { Welcome } from '../../ui/pages/welcome';

Meteor.startup(() => {
  render(
    <Provider store={ store }>
      <Router history={ history }>
        <Route path="/" component={ App }>
          <IndexRoute component={ Welcome } />
        </Route>
      </Router>
    </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'));
});
```

store.js

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { rootReducer } from '../reducers/root_reducer';
import { ui } from './ui_store';

const defaultState = { ui };

export const store = createStore(rootReducer, defaultState,
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__());

export const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);
```

ui_store.js

```
export const ui = {
  isSigninModalActive: false,
};
```

root_reducer.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux';
import { ui } from './ui_reducer';

export const rootReducer = combineReducers({ ui, routing: routerReducer });
```

ui_reducer.js

```
import update from 'immutability-helper';
import { toggleBodyOverflow } from '../modules/toggle_body_overflow';

export const ui = (state = null, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ONTOGGLE_MODAL_SIGNIN': {
      toggleBodyOverflow(!state.isSigninModalActive);
      document.getElementById('signin-modal__container').classList.toggle('active');
      return update(state, { isSigninModalActive: { $set: !state.isSigninModalActive } });
    }
    default: return state;
  }
};
```

ui_action.js

```
export const onToggleModal = modal => ({ type: `ONTOGGLE_MODAL_${modal.toUpperCase()}` });
```

**EDIT: I found the reason why app is re-rendering**

On my app container, I have set `mapStateToProps` and sent the `state.ui` down the components as props. I "fixed" it by removing it. Is this the correct way to stop re-rendering the whole app?

app_container.js

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as ui from '../../actions/ui';
import { App } from '../layouts/app_layout';

// problem: const mapStateToProps = state => { ui: state.ui };
const mapStateToProps = () => ({});
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators(ui, dispatch);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Comment: Uh... I can't say for sure right now why your whole application is re-rendering, but your reducer is _very_ wrong at the moment.  It should **absolutely not be modifying the DOM!!!**.  First, direct DOM manipulation is the wrong approach in a React app.  Second, reducers are only supposed to create new values based on the state and action parameters, without modifying anything.

Comment: Oh I see! Thanks!! So should I `store.subscribe` on the `signin_modal.jsx` component and change it's local state to equal `store.ui.isSigninModalActive` to re-render? Also I found out why the whole app is re-rendering. I "fixed" it but could you take a look? I'll edit my post above in a minute.

Comment: @cocacrave Don't use `store.subscribe` at all. That's what `connect` is doing for you. Your reducer should return only `{active: true}` or `{active: false}.` Your root components then should get this state as a property from `connect` and pass it to subcomponents.

Comment: @Sulthan Sorry, could you help me a little more? In the root component, `app_container`, if I send props `ui` object to children components then when `ui.active` toggles on and off, the whole application re-renders. In other words, any change in store's ui object re-renders the entire application since the state as prop changes in the root component. Is this supposed to happen? Shouldn't it only update one child component but not irrelevant component under the same parent component? That's why I used `store.subscribe` in a child component and removed state as props. What do you recommend I do?

Comment: @cocacrave You should be sending only what's needed. Don't send the whole `ui` to all subcomponents. A component shouldn't know anything about state or actions. A component should have a clear interface, e.g. a prop `isActive` and a `onClick` handler. The parent component should read the state and populate those properties. Then the components will be rerendered only when their properties change. If you manipulate the state correctly, you can also put `PureComponent` everywhere to improve performance.

Comment: @Sulthan Thanks!! I was sending the whole ui down from the app_container. Thanks for taking your time and clarifying things for me.